# How to configure lightbend/typesafeConfig via command line parameter when using picocli

Tags: java, environment-variables, command-line-arguments, typesafe-config, picocli

In our project we are using [Lightbend Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) / TypesafeConfig.

I can run my program with `java -jar`. The configuration of my program can also be done by using command line parameters.

Example:

```
java -jar simpleclient.jar -Dservice.url="http://localhost:8123"
```

Now I introduced https://picocli.info/ to have a better command line handling for my application.

The problem I'm facing now ist, that picocli doesn't allow  the usage of -D... parameters in the standard configuration.

How can this be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say “picocli doesn’t allow the use of -D... options”, I assume you mean you want to allow end users to set system properties with the `-Dkey=value` syntax. When such parameters are passed to the application, the application needs to use these values to set system properties, as shown below.

First, users can set system properties by passing `-Dkey=value` parameters to the `java` process instead of to the main class in the jar. In the below invocation, the system properties are set directly and are not passed as parameters to the application:

```
java -Dservice.url="http://localhost:8123"  -jar simpleclient.jar
```

Secondly, you can define a `-D` option in your application that sets system properties:

```
@Command
class SimpleClient {

    @Option(names = "-D")
    void setProperty(Map<String, String> props) {
        props.forEach((k, v) -> System.setProperty(k, v == null ? "" : v));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I modified the example a little bit to deal with `null` values which may happen when picocli 4.6 starts supporting `-Dkey` arguments in addition to `-Dkey=value`. See https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/1214

Comment: Inspired by your question, I also added this section to the user manual: https://picocli.info/#_system_properties